# Ubuntu 14.04 Chromium causes black screen

Tags: 14.04, chromium

While using chromium normally, some URL's cause my computer to go black screen. Computer works fine but cant see anything. Can change to console using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> but still black screen (I think the screen is shut down). I had to reboot using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Del</kbd>.
Is this a chromium bug? The URL's in question seem to have some sort of animation. This is one of them:

http://www.spacecraftforall.com/

If you have some information on this bug or know how to fix it, please say something.

Thank You.

Comment: about:gpu run this in chromium browser and please have a note on flash

Comment: ppapi-flash-version=13.0.0.182. Is this Stage3D related?

Comment: I've been having this problem on a newly installed 14.04 on a lenovo X61.  Did you ever get this figured out?

Comment: I actually switched to Firefox, it's faster and has no bug. I removed the firefox search box and I also synchronize bookmarks, so now it's just like chromium, only better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A workaround is now working on chromium 41.0.2272.76:

- Go to the Costumize and control icon at the top-right of chromium
  (the triple bar icon)
- Choose Settings
- Choose Show Advanced Settings
- Look for "System"
- Untick "use hardware acceleration when available"

I can now see and use the refered page without any known problem.

Answer (score 4):

You may try this and comment the result:

1. open up chromium and type this in address bar: **chrome://flags**
2. enable "override software rendering list" (the first item) then restart the browser.
3. load the youtube or whichever website you were having problem on, and check whether you are having same problem. If yes then comment

[source](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2205942&p=12943842#post12943842)

Comment: It starts loading, and then goes black screen just like before. Still having the same problem.

Comment: @lapisdecor this issue is only chromium ? did you tried on firefox, chrome ? do you have graphics card ?

Comment: please review the original post comments. Firefox works fine. This happens on a toshiba laptop, Intel 965GM x86/MMX/SSE2 card.

Comment: @lapisdecor I assume that its not dedicated like nvidia or amd. if its integrated then I cant help or even search for. might be a bug. better use firefox or opera(since new opera is made from chromium)

Comment: @lapisdecor my friend had similar problem with opera(newer one) this method helped him, just keep this method for future use ;-) for you it might be a bug, consider reporting it

Comment: Bug report done on chromium issues site. It could also be a OS bug since it's kind of a security issue (reboot needed). Firefox is the best answer to this problem.